# Animate through multiple pages with UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uipageviewcontroller

I am using UIPageViewController to create a horizontal list of pages. I want to have a button that will cause a transition to a specific page. I can do this by using `setViewControllers`.

```
setViewControllers(
    [viewController],
    direction: .forward,
    animated: true,
    completion: nil
)
```

However this will not animate over multiple pages. The animation makes it appear that the new page is directly next to the old page, even if it's not. An example of the animation I'm thinking of is hitting the home button on the iOS home screen.

One thing I've tried is starting another animation in the completion handler, but for some reason there is no animation on the second transition.

```
setViewControllers(
    [viewController],
    direction: .forward,
    animated: true,
    completion: { _ in
        // Second Transition
        self.setViewControllers(
            [nextViewController],
            direction: .forward,
            animated: true,
            completion: nil
        )
    }
)
```

Comment: Do you know how many "pages" you'll have? `UIPageViewController` may not be the best option.

Comment: UIPageViewController has a fixed amount of animations and each one's function is fixed. UIPageViewController doesn't support custom animations so you are either stuck with the default ones, or I suggest searching for libraries which might work the way you intended but implementing them in your code might be more work than its worth. Using completion blocks are hacky here plus the user can interrupt with touches.

Comment: This view will have over 40 pages. I've decided to use UICollectionView instead and to use `scrollToItem(at:at:animated:)`.